# Integrate $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I apologize if this is trivial, but I haven't had to do integral calculus in a while and I can't for the life of me remember how to find the indefinite integral

$$\int{\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}\,dx =?$$

I've tried a quick google and nothing came up.
Wolfram tells me the

$$\int{\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}} = \sqrt{x^2+1} +C$$

Which makes perfect sense to me if I differentiate it, but I cannot seem to remember how that can be determined backwards, apart from just memorizing.

Comment: Try substitution $t=1+x^2$.

Comment: Scalar multiple of this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450390/integral-of-frac2x-sqrt1x2?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use
$$
\cosh^2 u-\sinh^2 u=1
$$ by setting $$x:=\sinh u$$ giving
$$
(1+x^2)^{1/2}=(1+\sinh^2 u)^{1/2}=(\cosh^2 u)^{1/2}=\cosh u.
$$ Then

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \int\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^{1/2}}dx&=\int\frac{\sinh u}{\cosh u}\:\cosh u \:du\\\\
> &=\int\sinh u\:du\\\\
> &=\cosh u+C\\\\
> &=\sqrt{1+x^2}+C.
> \end{align}
> $$

Comment: Ah thank you, I see the problem is that when I took integral calculus, we didn't cover hyperbolic trig functions, but the textbook I'm using for ODEs seems to expect I either have some knowledge of them, or simply have an intuition of when it's the results of a trivial chain rule.

Comment: @awiebe $\cosh u$ is just a shortcut for $(e^u+e^{-u})/2$, and many properties are not difficult to understand :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: let $u=1+x^2$ then $du=\dots$.

Comment: if u= 1+x^2 then du/dx =2x => du=2dx
$$\int{x/u}du =do I have ro solve for x in terms of u to get rid of the other x?

Comment: A typo:  du=2xdx.  So the "other x" is accounted for...

Answer (score 1):

let, $x=\tan \theta\implies dx=\sec^2\theta \ d\theta$ $$\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\ dx$$ 
$$=\int \frac{\tan\theta}{(1+\tan^2\theta)^{1/2}}\ (\sec^2\theta \ d\theta)$$
$$=\int \frac{\tan\theta\sec^2\theta }{(\sec^2\theta)^{1/2}}\ \ d\theta$$
$$=\int \frac{\tan\theta\sec^2\theta}{\sec\theta}\  d\theta$$
$$=\int \sec\theta\tan\theta\  d\theta$$
$$=\int d(\sec\theta)=\sec\theta+C$$$$=\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}+C$$
$$=\color{blue}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+C}$$